# Group By with Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Table which has following columns.

[image]

I want to get results with the same number of columns but with sum of running Balance with Account code not repeating more than once 
i tried this query

```
select  AccountCode , 'All Companies' as divisionName , AcName , LF_AccountType , Sum(ISNULL(runningBalance,0)) as  runningBalance  from Table
group by AccountCode , divisionName , AcName , LF_AccountType
```

Comment: The query should work. What the heck went wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that the `AcName` for an `AccountCode` have different whitespace? Maybe try trimming that column?

Comment: Because you are using a fixed value, just use an aggregation function with it and remove it from the GROUP BY clause. Take a look at the update i made to the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Because you are using a fixed value, just use an aggregation function with it and remove it from the `GROUP BY` clause , it will not make sense. As example:

```
SELECT AccountCode  , AcName , LF_AccountType ,  
        MIN('All Companies') as divisionName, 
        SUM(ISNULL(runningBalance,0)) as  runningBalance  from Table
group by AccountCode ,  AcName , LF_AccountType
```

## Workarounds

TRY using Windows Function with subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM (

    Select  AccountCode , 'All Companies' as divisionName , AcName , LF_AccountType , 
    Sum(ISNULL(runningBalance,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY LF_AccountType ) as  runningBalance  , 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LF_AccountType) as rn
    from Table

) AS T1 WHERE T1.rn = 1
```

Or use subqueries with Group by

```
Select  'All Companies' as divisionName, *  From (


select  AccountCode , AcName , 
LF_AccountType , Sum(ISNULL(runningBalance,0)) as  runningBalance  
from Table
group by AccountCode, AcName , LF_AccountType

) T1
```

Answer (score 2):

it's unclear what your problem is.  However, All columns in the group by statement must be in or derived from the tables queried.  So you can't use divisionname in your group by.   And you don't need it.
So, the immediate syntactic fix would be:

```
select  AccountCode , 'All Companies' as divisionName , AcName , 
LF_AccountType , Sum(ISNULL(runningBalance,0)) as  runningBalance  
from Table
group by AccountCode, AcName , LF_AccountType
```